# Rails change_column migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this inside `create_table`:

```
t.string 'email', :default => '', :null => false
```

And then in another migration have this:

```
change_column('admin_users', 'email', :string, :limit => 100)
```

After I run everything, in schema.rb I get this:

```
t.string "email", limit: 100, default: "", null: false
```

Wasn't `change_column` supposed to overwrite everything in the previous definition? Why did `:default` and `null` were left? I was watching a tutorial where it said `change_column` overwrites everything. Was there some recent Rails version when this was changed?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, `change_column` does not erase previously-set details. Let's say you were changing the column so you could simply add a `NULL` constraint. It wouldn't make sense to have to add in all the other previously-set contraints as well.

If you want to change the `default` or `null` settings, just do so in the `change_column` method.

```
change_column('admin_users', 'email', :string, :limit => 100, :default => "", :null => true)
```

Otherwise, to erase everything, do `remove_column` then `add_column`:

```
remove_column('admin_users', 'email')
add_column('admin_users', 'email', :string, :limit => 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`change_column` doesn't overwrite everything, it just makes the changes you specify.  So it added the limit to the column, but that's all.